ffmpeg from DVVideo AVI to H.265 fails to play but AVI to MPEG to H.265 works
I've been pulling old camcorder video from my Sony Digital8 camera from Hi8 tapes. The Sony software creates AVI files that ffprobe detects as:
[avi @ 000001dec87682c0] ODML index invalid
Last message repeated 1 times
Input #0, avi, from '.\20240717154604.avi':
  Duration: 01:57:00.11, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 29803 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: dvvideo (dvsd / 0x64737664), yuv411p, 720x480 [SAR 8:9 DAR 4:3], 28771 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 29.97 tbn
  Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 32000 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1024 kb/s

If I convert the file to mpg using: -target ntsc-dvd -b:v 9M -q:a 2 -q:v 2 -channel_layout stereo
Then convert it to H.265 MP4 using: -c:v libx265 -crf 27 -preset slow -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ac 2
The resulting file works in the Windows Media app and, more importantly, in Plex. However, if I convert from the DVVideo AVI directly to H.265 the Windows Media app tells me it's an unsupported codec and Plex thinks it's playing it but it has no video or audio.
I've tried with all these different arguments to convert directly from the AVI to H.265. Note, my laptop has both Intel and nVidia chipsets, that's why I tried both hevc_qsv and hevc_nvenc.
-c:v libx265 -crf 27 -preset slow -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ac 2
-map 0 -c copy -c:v hevc_qsv -c:a aac
-c copy -c:v hevc_nvenc
-c copy -c:v hevc_nvenc -preset slow -level 4.1 -f mp4
-c:v hevc_nvenc -preset slow -level 4.1 -f mp4

The rest of the command line was the same for each attempt: ffmpeg.exe -i ".\Input.avi" -ss 00:00:06.966 -to 00:20:04.766 <args from a line above> "X:\Output.mp4"
Here is the ffprobe output for a resulting mp4 converted from mpeg that works:
PS X:\> .\ffmpeg\bin\ffprobe.exe -hide_banner '.\Hiner Christmas 1997 - nVidia mpg copy preset slow level 4.1.mp4'
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '.\Hiner Christmas 1997 - nVidia mpg copy preset slow level 4.1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomdby1iso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf60.16.100
  Duration: 00:19:58.01, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2488 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: hevc (Main) (hev1 / 0x31766568), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 720x480 [SAR 8:9 DAR 4:3], 2035 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc60.31.102 hevc_nvenc
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: ac3 (ac-3 / 0x332D6361), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 448 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
    Side data:
      audio service type: main

And here's one from the resulting mp4 file converted from avi that does not work:
PS X:\> .\ffmpeg\bin\ffprobe.exe -hide_banner '.\Hiner Christmas 1997 - nVidia avi copy preset slow level 4.1.mp4'
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '.\Hiner Christmas 1997 - nVidia avi copy preset slow level 4.1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf60.16.100
  Duration: 00:19:57.81, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3064 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: hevc (Rext) (hev1 / 0x31766568), yuv444p(tv, bottom coded first (swapped)), 720x480 [SAR 8:9 DAR 4:3], 2033 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc60.31.102 hevc_nvenc
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: pcm_s16le (ipcm / 0x6D637069), 32000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1024 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]

One clear difference is that the video for the working file is
hevc (Main) (hev1 / 0x31766568), yuv420p(tv, progressive)
and for the bad one is
hevc (Rext) (hev1 / 0x31766568), yuv444p(tv, bottom coded first (swapped)).
Likewise, the audio for the good one is
ac3 (ac-3 / 0x332D6361), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 448 kb/s (default)
and for the bad one is
pcm_s16le (ipcm / 0x6D637069), 32000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1024 kb/s (default).
I don't understand ffmpeg or Plex quite well enough to know which of those might be a problem or quite how to fix it.
Note, all the files will play in VLC because it will ingest just about anything and play it but I'd really like to figure out how to get these working on Plex without having to convert to DVD compatible MPEG then to H.265 because that would surely degrade the quality to some degree.

If it works in VLC that means there's at least one codec that supports all the "specificity" of the resulting container. VLC has its own set of codecs, it neither depends on system wide installed codecs nor "shares" its own codecs to other programs. It should be a matter of installing the right codec at the OS level.

https://superuser.com/a/1849676/788170 Just use .ac3, not .flac, or you won't retain the 6+ channel audio.

-vf yadif -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx265 -crf 27 -preset slow -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ac 2

The fix is to change the pixel format to yuv420p.
Plex will play the video in that format, and works with either aac or ac3 audio.
The final command line I used for my first successful attempt was:
ffmpeg.exe -hide_banner -i ".\Input.avi" -ss 00:00:06.966 -to 00:20:04.766 -map 0 -c copy -c:v hevc_qsv -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a ac3 -preset slow ".\Output.mp4"
I do not believe using the Intel codec matters in this case. I believe either -c:v hevc_nvenc or -c:v libx265 would work the same.
(@Gyan Though I discovered the fix before I saw your comment, that likely would have fixed it so if you write it up as an answer, I'll accept it.)

Side note, in the midst of all the testing, -c:v hevc_nvenc stopped working. It told me the hardware didn't support it, even though it had worked fine recently. I ended up having to reinstall my Nvidia drivers and now the Nvidia encoder works again. Just wanted to note that in case someone else has that kind of issue.

I note that the HEVC parameters are slightly different. But I would start with the audio: ac3 is a good bet. You could also try deleting the audio entirely to rule that out and just investigate which video stream is preferred.
